# What do I need to know to create Linux GUI elemnts

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface

I'm looking to start developing Linux, specifically graphical elements and visuals. For example, the gnome-panel. I would be developing graphical interfaces like that. So the question is, what do I need to know? What resources do I need? I've looked all around for resources and I've discovered qt (of course) FVWM, and looked through an archived version of lynucs.org. So, what should I begin with? I haven't found a single tutorial on creating graphical elements for linux, so hopefully someone here can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: If you're interested in gnome-panel and similar, why don't you go look for gnome sources & tutorials? You'll quickly find tons & tons of stuff.

Comment: Come on, man! **Linux is all about the COMMAND LINE, h4x0r style.** Linux users don't need a GUI... only Windows weaklings like myself do :)

Comment: It doesn't have to be.

Comment: and I'm not necessarily interested in the gnome pane, that's just an example.

Comment: This presumes there _are_ Linux GUI elements. That's just not true, which is why you can't find tutorials. Linux supports a number of GUI environments and each defines its own GUI elements. Those have tutorials. I'd advice Qt.

Answer (score 3):

In Qt you have a very good documentation. You can start with some easy tutorials and than work on with more advanced concepts.

Here is a good starting point: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/gettingstarted.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to develop desktop components that integrate with Linux desktops, then the answer is not straightforward. Depending on the desktop environment you develop for, you have to use different libraries.
If it is for Gnome, then definitely look into [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/), or more recently [Javascript](https://live.gnome.org/Gjs).
If it is for KDE, then you should use [Qt](http://qt-project.org), as KDE is written entirely in Qt.

Answer (score 0):

For working on gnome-panel (or some other GNOME component), you could look into [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/).